# Did Crimean Tatars collaborate with Nazi Germany's crimes against humanity?

Tags: ukraine, nazi-germany

The article [Tell Eurovision in 1944 Stalin deported Crimean Tatars to protect them from punishment for Nazi war crimes, by Scott](http://thesaker.is/tell-eurovision-in-1944-stalin-deported-crimean-tatars-to-protect-them-from-punishment-for-nazi-war-crimes-by-scott/) (13672 views, 64 comments) claims that Crimean Tatars collaborated with Nazi Germany's crimes against humanity.

> What Washington is omitting that collaborating with German Turks
>   actively participated in the genocide of Russians in occupied Crimea.
>
> From archive of NKVD so called “Special Files. message #465/B” “Jankoy
>   district, a group of three Tatars was arrested who by the German order
>   executed in gas chambers 200 Gypsies.” “In Sudak, 19
>   Tatar-executioners were arrested. they violently executed Red Army
>   servicemen captured by Germans. From those arrested, Osman Setarov
>   personally shot 37 soldiers.  Osman Abdureshidov shot 38 soldiers of
>   the Red Army.”
>
> ...
>
> However, these sort of direct battles with the regular Red Army
>   regiments were unusual for Turks. They much preferred to deal with the
>   civilian population and POWs, the way they have dealt in Turkey with
>   the non-Turkish population. SS Crimean-Tatar Battalion burned alive
>   15,000 Russians, Ukrainians, Greeks and Armenias, the entire
>   population of village Mirnoe (Peaceful)
>
> During the occupation of Crimea, Germans and Romanians organized 116
>   death camps staffed with Crimean Turks. They were organized by Schuma
>   organization into 152 battalion. For the exception of 6 military
>   officers, all 320 servicemen in this battalion were Crimean “Tatar”
>   Turks.   For example death camp “Red” also known as Crimean
>   Buchenvald. In this death camp people were executed, without a chance
>   to get out.
>
> In two years of German, Romanian and Turkish occupation of Crimes,
>   over 90,000 civilians were murdered and over 85,000 were trafficked to
>   Germany for forced labor Only about 2% of those people survived and
>   returned.
>
> In nearby so called “internment” camp, out of 140,000 people interned,
>   40,000 were murdered and 100,000 were trafficked to Germany for forced
>   labor. Turks working in the death camp “Red” were “creative” in the
>   ways they murdered people. They drowned mothers with children in
>   cesspools. They mass burned people alive by tying them up with
>   barbwire, pouring gasoline on them and setting them on fire. Just
>   compare, for 7 years in Buchenvald 56,000 people were killed. 8,000
>   per year. In death camp “Red” in less than 2 years Germans, Romanians
>   and Turks murdered 15,000 people. The prevailing notion that the
>   majority people killed in these particular death camps were Jews, is
>   wrong. The majority of people killed there were Russians.

By comparison, the Wikipedia article [Ukrainian collaborationism with the Axis powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_collaborationism_with_the_Axis_powers) only mentions the Crimean Tatars once, as an ethnic group which was the victim of racism along others such as Jews and Roma (gypsies):

> Original reasons for collaboration included Ukrainian political aspirations for regaining independence, resurgent nationalism, but also widespread anger and resentment against the Russians over the genocide by famine engineered in Soviet Ukraine only a few years earlier. These sentiments were coupled with rampant racism towards other ethnic groups (such as Jews, Tatars, Roma people, and Poles) as well as the prevailing notions of anti-Semitism.

Did Crimean Tatars collaborate with Nazi Germany's crimes against humanity (as opposed to merely supporting them militarily - the article specifically claims they did the former in the sentence starting "They much preferred to deal with the civilian population and POWs"), and did they do so willingly (as opposed to being [kapos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapo_(concentration_camp)))?

Comment: A site with a Russian black-and-brown stripe on the home page? It may require more than usual two independent sources to prove what its claims.

Comment: in 1944 the Crimean ASSR was part of the Russian SFSR, not the Ukrainian SSR (at least in Soviet terms)

Comment: This will probably do better on [history.se], what do you think?

Comment: In an ideal world, anything with the suspected taint of nonsense would be on skeptics.SE, and other stack exchanges would be pristine and unpolluted, but I'm happy to let it be migrated.

Comment: @bytebuster what does brown and black represent?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is asked here. I have no doubts, that there were Nazi collaborators among all of the national groups in USSR you can possibly imagine (barring near-extinct ones). The article claims ~320 Crimean Tatar collaborators, which is perfectly in line with relative % in other ethnic groups (actually, noticeably smaller than a typical number), considering >200000 Tatar population at that time. The claims about the numbers seem reasonable. But again, the answer to "Did -insert ethnic group- collaborate with Nazi Germany?" is almost always "yes".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, "*The ribbon […] was also used by the anti-Soviet Russian Liberation Army that **fought alongside Nazi Germany** during World War II*" — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_of_Saint_George#History)

Comment: I agree with @sashkello. The claim worded as "did" (meaning at all) is irrelevant to anything and overly trivial. Every population had its collaborators. Such a claim has zero bearing on the issue of Stalin's deportation, which involved everyone. If the claim is to be worded as "did all/most..." (which would at least be a plausible one to being into the Stalin argument), then the source - nor anyone else - seems to be NOT making that claim so it's not notable

Comment: @user5341 are there any factual claims in that article that you dispute, or are you willing to accept every factual claim in that article as true? Should I instead ask, rather than whether individual Crimean Tatars collaborated with Nazi crimes against humanity, whether the ethnic group was collectively guilty of helping the Nazis in their crimes against humanity?

Comment: @andrew don't worry about the criticism of irrelevance or triviality. Claims only need to be believed by many people (notable), sufficiently fact based (as opposed to opinion), and not too broad

Comment: @Dawn I clearly stated why I think the question is bad, and it doesn't involve the fact that the answer is "yes". It's bad as it is now because it is trivial and actually contains answer within itself.